# antd Switch UI doesn't update after submit

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

I new with ANTD and have the same problem and I can't understand the solution, please help!
here is my code:

```
<Switch valuePropName="value" onChange={(evt) => setAccountsData({...accountsData, active: evt})}/>
```

after submit the state getting back to false but the button is still **checked**,
how do I unchecked the switch after submit?

Comment: could you include the code related to form? Are you using `Switch` with `Form` component?

Comment: no, but I think I found a solution, I added checked attribute

Answer (score 0):

If `Switch` is inside a form, you can reset the form using the [form hook](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-control-hooks) method `resetForm`

```js
const [form] = Form.useForm();

const handleChange = checked => {
  setAccountsData({ ...accountsData, active: checked }).then(() => {
    form.resetFields();
  })
}

return (
  <Form form={form}>
    <Form.Item name="foo">
      <Switch valuePropName="value" onChange={handleChange}(evt) => }/>
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
)
```

Although i'm just assuming, ideally you can provide more code for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, just added the **check** attribute.
so it looks like that:

```
<Switch checked={accountsData.active === false ? false : true} 
        onChange={(evt) => setAccountsData({...accountsData, active: evt})}
/>
```